# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' on tensor definition for Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, typeerror, tensor

I'm trying to create a tensor for TensorFlow using a 64 line FEN code for chess notation, but I'm getting a TypeError when trying to define the tensor. I'm new to TensorFlow, so apologies if this is a noob question. I can't seem to find a similar question online, however. My X values are one column per board piece, combined with a "white" or "black" value for whose turn it is. The evaluations are numbers that denote who's winning that I converted to simple "white" or "black".

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
df = pd.read_csv ('medchessData.csv')
#rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR
allgames=[]
for game in df.FEN.values:
    values = game.split(' ')
    game = values[0]
    currentgameboard=["X" for i in range(65)]
    if values[1] == "w" or values[1] == "b":
        turn = values[1]
        currentgameboard[64]=turn
    squareval=0
    for value in game:
        if value == "/":
            continue
        try:
            value = int(value)
        except:
            pass
        if value in range (-5,30):
            squareval+=int(value)
            continue
        currentgameboard[squareval]=value
        squareval+=1
    allgames.append(currentgameboard)

evaluations=[]
for evaluation in df.Evaluation.values:
    #evalsign = "neg" if evaluation[0] == "-" else "pos"
    #eval = int(evaluation[1:])
    #if evalsign == "neg":
        #eval=eval*-1
    if evaluation[0]=="#":
        evaluation=evaluation[1:]
    try:
        evaluations.append(int(evaluation))
    except:
        try:
          evaluation=evaluation[-1:]
          evaluations.append(int(evaluation))
        except:
            try:
                evaluation=evaluation[-2:]
                evaluations.append(int(evaluation))
            except:
              evaluation=evaluation[-3:]
              evaluations.append(int(evaluation))
for i in range(len(evaluations)):
    if evaluations[i]>1:
        evaluations[i]="white"
    elif evaluations[i]<1:
        evaluations[i]="black"
    else:
        evaluations[i]="tie"
print(evaluations[0:10])
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
allgamestrans=[]
for game in allgames:
    le.fit(game)
    le.classes_
    allgamestrans.append(le.transform(game))
X = pd.DataFrame(allgames)
y = pd.DataFrame(evaluations)
X=X.join(y,lsuffix='_')
X.rename(columns={ X.columns[65]: "label" }, inplace = True)

print(X.head())
print(y.head())
X.to_csv('X.csv',index=False)
y.to_csv('y.csv',index=False)
print(X.index)
print(y.index)
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
print("starting")
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import feature_column
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
dataframe=X
train, val, test = np.split(dataframe.sample(frac=1), [int(0.8*len(dataframe)), int(0.9*len(dataframe))])
print(len(train), 'training examples')
print(len(val), 'validation examples')
print(len(test), 'test examples')
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  df = dataframe.copy()
  labels = X.pop("label")
  df = {key: value[:,tf.newaxis] for key, value in dataframe.items()}
  import numpy as np
  np.array(labels)[:, None]
**  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(df), labels))
**  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  ds = ds.prefetch(batch_size)
  return ds
batch_size = 5 # A small batch sized is used for demonstration purposes
train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, y, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, y, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, y, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
# We will use this batch to demonstrate several types of feature columns
example_batch = next(iter(train_ds))[0]
def demo(feature_column):
  feature_layer = layers.DenseFeatures(feature_column)
  print(feature_layer(example_batch).numpy())
crossed_feature = feature_column.crossed_column([age_buckets, animal_type], hash_bucket_size=64)
demo(feature_column.indicator_column(crossed_feature))
feature_columns = []
for i in range(64):
    feature_columns.append(feature_column.indicator_column(str(i)))
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dropout(.1),
  layers.Dense(1)
])
print("compiling")
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print("fitting")
model.fit(train_ds,
          validation_data=val_ds,
          epochs=10)
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_ds)
print("Accuracy", accuracy)
```

The output is:

```
['black', 'white', 'black', 'white', 'black', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white']
  0_  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ... 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64  label
0  r  n  b  q  k  b  n  r  p  p  ...  R  N  B  Q  K  B  N  R  b  black
1  r  n  b  q  k  b  n  r  p  p  ...  R  N  B  Q  K  B  N  R  w  white
2  r  n  b  q  k  b  n  r  p  p  ...  R  N  B  Q  K  B  N  R  b  black
3  r  n  b  q  k  b  n  r  p  p  ...  R  N  B  Q  K  B  N  R  w  white
4  r  n  b  q  k  b  n  r  p  p  ...  R  X  B  Q  K  B  N  R  b  black

[5 rows x 66 columns]
       0
0  black
1  white
2  black
3  white
4  black
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=196482, step=1)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=196482, step=1)
starting
157185 training examples
19648 validation examples
19649 test examples
<ipython-input-35-39422f4fd435>:90: FutureWarning: Support for multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.  Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.
  df = {key: value[:,tf.newaxis] for key, value in dataframe.items()}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-39422f4fd435> in <cell line: 100>()
     98   return ds
     99 batch_size = 5 # A small batch sized is used for demonstration purposes
--> 100 train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, y, batch_size=batch_size)
    101 val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, y, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
    102 test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, y, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/util/structure.py in normalize_element(element, element_signature)
     91   normalized_components = []
     92   if element_signature is None:
---> 93     components = nest.flatten(element)
     94     flattened_signature = [None] * len(components)
     95     pack_as = element

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Sorry if a version of this question has been asked before, all I can find are unrelated TypeErrors not relevant to tensors.

I'm at a loss on what to try, as I'm following the guidelines here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/preprocessing_layers and I believe I'm doing it as directed. I was expected to create a NeuralNet